# Compare DateTime as a string into a LINQ to Entities doesn't recognize DateTime.parse(string)

Tags: c#, .net, linq, entity-framework, datetime

I'm developing a WCF RESTful service with C#, .NET Framework 4.0 and **Entity Framework Code First**.

I have this class (that represents a table on database):

```
[DataContract]
public class PostLine
{
    public int PostLineId { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public int? UserId { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string DateUtc { get; set; }

    public User Author { get; set; }
}
```

And I'm trying to do this:

```
DateTime fourDaysAgo = DateTime.Now.Date.AddDays(-4);

var postLines = 
    context.PostLines.Where(p => DateTime.Compare(DateTime.Parse(p.DateUtc), fourDaysAgo) > 0).Include("Author");
```

But I get the following error:

`{System.NotSupportedException: LINQ to Entities doesn't recognize the method 'System.DateTime Parse(System.String)', which can not be converted into an expression of the repository.`

I need that `PostLine.DateUtc` to be a string because I'm going to use it on my web service, and send it as JSON, so its better for me to store it as a string.

If I use `DateTime` type, I'm going to get something like this on JSON response:

```
{
    "DateUtc": "/Date(1380924000000+0200)/",
    "Description": "post_1",
    "UserId": 1
}
```

**Do you know how can I compare a string with a DateTime on a LINQ expression?**

Comment: Why isn't `DateUtc` a `DateTime`? Your JSON serializer should be handling this parsing.

Comment: Yes, but how do you parse `"/Date(1380924000000+0200)/"` on iOS and on Android?

Comment: Relevant link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10286204/the-right-json-date-format So I can sympathize with the string property used here.

Comment: `1380924000000` is the milliseconds since the 1970 epoch, `+0200` is the time zone. It should be possible to parse that out with almost any date/time library. What is the `string` format used? It might be comparable with `string.Compare` if it's the ISO standard and no time zones are involved.

Comment: Could you send me your `web/app.config`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the best approach will be to split the property in two.

Entity Framework wants a `DateTime` property. That makes perfect sense.

For serialization you want a `string` property. That also makes perfect sense.

However, you're trying to use a single property for both, and that doesn't make sense, and isn't necessary.

```
[DataContract]
public class PostLine
{
    ...

    public DateTime DateUtcAsDateTime { get; set; }

    [DataMember, NotMapped]
    public string DateUtcAsString {
        get { return DateUtcAsDateTime.ToString(); }
        set { DateUtcAsDateTime = DateTime.Parse(value); }
    }

    ...
}
```

Now, `DateUtcAsDateTime` will be used by Entity Framework, and `DateUtcAsString` will be ignored by Entity Framework as it has a `NotMapped` attribute.

`DateUtcAsString`, on the other hand, is the only one of these properties that has a `DataMember` attribute, so should be the only one that gets serialized.

You can of course rename one of these properties back to `DateUtc`, if you want.

**Update**: as Matt Johnson points out, an improvement would be to specify the format in a way that always results in the exact same string. This ensures your strings don't change, just because your code gets moved to another server that happens to have different regional settings.

```
[DataMember, NotMapped]
public string DateUtcAsString {
    get { return DateUtcAsDateTime.ToString("o"); }
    set { DateUtcAsDateTime = DateTime.Parse(value, "o", null, DateTimeStyles.AssumeUniversal | DateTimeStyles.AdjustToUniversal); }
}
```

Note that I am using `DateTimeStyles.AssumeUniversal | DateTimeStyles.AdjustToUniversal` instead of the `DateTimeStyles.RoundTripKind` that he suggested, because the name `DateUtc` strongly suggests you *always* want UTC, never local time. And I'm not specifying any culture explicitly, as the `"o"` format is already independent of culture.

You could, if it's easier for your other code to handle, use `"r"` instead of `"o"` with the same benefits.

Comment: -1 Serialization should not affect the implementation of the class. It is possible to change the behavior of the JsonDataContractSerializer and Newtonsoft's Serializer.

Comment: @Aron I agree that that would probably be even better, and if you post an answer that gets that working, so long as it's done in a way that has no unexpected side effects (including other code that may rely on other `DateTime` properties being serialised the way they are now), it gets my vote. I've taken a similar approach to this answer myself in slightly different scenarios, because the extensibility I would otherwise need was simply missing, but perhaps that is not the case for this question.

Comment: @Aron BTW, thanks for explaining, that's always nicer than a downvote without comment.

Comment: I need to know the serializer that is being used. The two standards are the DataContractJsonSerializer and Newtonsoft's Json.Net...I think that DataContractJsonSerializer is being used...But without knowing how the serializer is being created I can't tell you how to set the Serializer DateTimeFormat property.

Comment: This approach isn't horrible, but it's certainly noisy.  If anything, the `"o"` string format and invariant culture should be specified, and it should probably use `ParseExact` with `RoundTripKind`.

Comment: @MattJohnson I agree with the `"o"` (or `"r"`, if sub-second precision is not needed, and that format happens to be easier to process on the other end), but if you're using a format that doesn't depend on culture, culture doesn't need to be specified anymore. As for `RoundTripKind`, the property is named `DateUtc`, so I think `AssumeUniversal | AdjustToUniversal` would make more sense, but the documentation suggests these don't really work right. I will edit my answer when I can do some testing (and it's possible that testing will show that your suggestion actually works better)

Answer (score 2):

This is certainly an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) if I ever saw one.  You're asking about comparing datetime as strings in Entity Framework, while it seems the real problem is that you don't like the default date format of the `DataContractJsonSerializer` that WCF uses by default.

Part of the problem is that you are mixing local and UTC.  You're getting `/Date(1380924000000+0200)/`, which contains the local time zone offset of the server.  This is because you started from `DateTime.Now`, which has a `.Kind` of `DateTimeKind.Local`.

If you instead used `DateTime.UtcNow`, it would have a `.Kind` of `DateTimeKind.Utc`, and would be serialized as `/Date(1380924000000)/`.  And yes, the numerical portion of the format would be the same.  Even when there is an offset specified, the number part is still related to UTC.

That's just one problem with this format.  The other is that while `DataContractJsonSerializer` writes the local offset during serialization, it doesn't use it properly during deserialization.  It just assumes that if *any* offset is provided, that the time should be local - *even if the computer doing the deserialization has a completely different offset*.

The better format to use in JSON is the ISO8601 format.  For example, this UTC value would look like `2013-10-04T22:00:00.000Z`.  And while you can easily pass in a different date format to `DataContractJsonSerializer` if you use it directly, WCF doesn't easily expose this to you.

You could go down the route of changing the `DataContractJsonSerializer` settings via a custom WCF message formatter, such as described [here](http://json.codeplex.com/discussions/209865), [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/endpoint/archive/2011/05/03/wcf-extensibility-message-formatters.aspx) and [here](http://wcfpro.wordpress.com/2011/03/03/idispatchmessageformatter/), but it gets complicated very quickly.  Be careful if you do this, and be sure to test thoroughly!

Another idea would be to write a custom WCF message formatter that uses [JSON.Net](http://json.net) instead of `DataContractJsonSerializer`.  JSON.Net uses the ISO8601 format by default, so you would be set.

But honestly, the best solution is to not try to use WCF to build your REST endpoints.  The date format issue is just the beginning.  There are all sorts of other problems that can pop up along the way.  Instead, use a modern framework that is designed for this purpose, such as [ASP.Net WebAPI](http://www.asp.net/web-api), or [ServiceStack](http://www.servicestack.net/).

ASP.Net WebAPI uses JSON.Net, and ServiceStack has it's own JSON serializer called ServiceStack.Text.  JSON.Net uses ISO8601 as it's default date format.  If you use Service Stack, you'll need to set `JsConfig.DateHandler = JsonDateHandler.ISO8601;`

So in recap, you have *two* XY problems:

- First, you chose WCF to build your rest endpoints, which was so problematic that the industry developed other solutions.
- Second, you couldn't get `DateTime` to emit the correct format, so you decided to treat it as a string, which then you couldn't compare back to a `DateTime` in an EF query.

And yes, I realize I didn't answer your question of how to compare a `DateTime` input against a string property in Entity Framework, but I think now you can see why.  If you *really* want to go down that road, you might find something useful in [`SqlFunctions`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.sqlclient.sqlfunctions.aspx) or [`EntityFunctions`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.entityfunctions.aspx) - but even then, how are you going to build an efficient index on this column in your database?  Querying will be really slow if you get a lot of data.  I would advise against it.

Comment: I checked the EF functions. There isn't a `DateTime.Parse` but come to think of it, you might be able to just use `Convert` or unsafe cast. Still at the end of the day, SEPARATION Of CONCERN people. Your Serialization logic and your persistence logic should be separate! But yeah...brilliant umm...not an answer.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how you are instantiating your `DataContractJsonSerializer`. If you are directly instantiating it...you can pass a `DataContractJsonSerializerSettings`, with a `DateTimeFormat` for setting how `DateTime` are serialized.

If you are using a behavior to instantiate your Serializer things are a little more complicated.

Comment: WCF creates the `DataContractJsonSerializer` automatically, and uses the constructor that doesn't supply any `DataContractorJsonSerializerSettings` or `DateTimeFormat` object.  If you dig deep enough, you can find it in `System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.SingleBodyParameterDataContractMessageFormatter.CreateSerializer`.

Comment: Well in theory you can inject your own with a behavior. However I agree that you really want to use WebAPI, which strangely enough uses Newtonsoft Json.NET (man they royally screwed up the `DataContractJsonSerializer`).

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to go down the route of using a string for your class when transfering your data to your client, you should have a separate DTO class.

You can then use a library like AutoMapper to map your `PostLine` class to `PostLineDto` with an expression.

However the next problem you will face then is that your `Expression<Func<PostLine,PostLineDto>>` will contain `Expression.MethodCall(DateTime.Parse)` and you will have to inject an `ExpressionVisitor` that can convert...

```
p => p.DateUtc > DateTime.Parse("2013 Aug 1") - bool
```

into

```
p => p.DateUtc > new DateTime(1, Aug, 2013) - bool
```

Which is a real pain.